# PHP: is the implode() function safe for multibyte strings?

Tags: php, multibyte, implode

The `explode()` function has a correlating multibyte-safe function in `mb_split()`.

I don't see a correlating function for `implode()`. Does this imply that implode is already safe for multibyte strings?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding why there needs to be a multi-byte safe `split()` in the first place - splitting a string is multi-byte safe by default, no? But that's a different question.

Comment: PHP stores all strings (AFAIK) as raw binary byte sequences, so in theory it should be possible to use `explode()` with multibyte strings as well, as long as you pass the correct binary representation of the split token. The same therefore applies to `implode()` - the binary sequence passed as the join delimiter will be used literally, so as long as your delimiter is correctly stored, there should be no problems.

Comment: @DaveRandom: isn't it possible that a multibyte character might look like two single-byte characters? If one of those single-byte characters happens to be the delimiter, isn't it possible that you might end up splitting on a multibyte character unintentionally?

Comment: Why would your string contain multibyte *and* single byte characters? Wouldn't that be a corrupt string anyway?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, where the boundary of two characters overlaps to create the sequence... Well in that case yes, I suppose it could - but that is getting into a depth at which I am not qualified to comment.

Comment: @daniel but in that case, you would have to be mixing two character sets, which is a circumstance that shouldn't happen? I can't quite get my head around it, but what you say probably points in the right direction. Maybe one needs to look beyond UTF-8 to understand this? I may ask a question about it later

Comment: @DaveRandom Except that `explode()` will not return a string as an array if you try to split on the empty string, which makes explode limited.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as your delimiter and the strings in the array contain only well-formed multibyte sequences there should not be any issues.

`implode` basically is a fancy concatenation operator and I couldn't imagine a scenario where concatenation is not multibyte safe ;)

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean by "well-formed multibyte sequence" in this context? (I agree with the rest, though)

Comment: Thanks. I'm using a space as a delimiter: `mb_split(' ', $mbstring)`. Does this constitute a well-formed multibyte sequence?

Comment: @danielfaraday it depends if your script is stored in the multibyte charset that your string uses. If it isn't, then no it isn't.

Comment: @DaveRandom: could you expound? I'm not sure what you mean by storing the script in a charset.

Comment: Well, if your script was stored (i.e. saved to disk by your editor, or whatever) in a single byte character set, then the `' '` would be a single byte space, which is probably not valid in the target charset

Comment: @Pekka Well, that the code point sequence is valid. I don't know how one could express that correctly. E.g. the delimiter should not have the first two bits set (in UTF-8), because it would form a character together with the next code point.

Comment: @Pekka Crap, I obviously mean code unit sequence, not code point sequence, sorry.