# excerpt(); function is not counting/working japanese words

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I am working on Japanese language web site, and using this code for         words limit, it is working when I paste English sentence but not working with Japanese words .

```
function content($num) {
$theContent = get_the_content();
$output = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', $theContent);
$output = preg_replace( '/<blockquote>.*<\/blockquote>/', '', $output );
$output = preg_replace( '|\[(.+?)\](.+?\[/\\1\])?|s', '', $output );
$limit = $num+1;
$content = explode(' ', $output, $limit);
array_pop($content);
$content = implode(" ",$content)."...";
  echo $content;
}


<?php content('15'); ?>
```

Can any body help me, and one thing is that I am using `xeory_extension` theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Japanese characters are multibyte (Hiragana and Katakana characters are stored on 3 bytes in UTF-8), so you'll have to use [special php multibytes string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) to manipulate strings that contains Japanese characters.

Sadly PHP doesn't provide a `mb_explode` function out of the box. Though some people worked on that, using `mb_strlen` and `mb_substr` to build up that missing function.

The following code is note mine, it comes from [the fetus-hina mb_explode gist](https://gist.github.com/fetus-hina/1868198):

```
function mb_explode($delimiter, $string, $limit = -1, $encoding = 'auto') {
    if(!is_array($delimiter)) {
        $delimiter = array($delimiter);
    }
    if(strtolower($encoding) === 'auto') {
        $encoding = mb_internal_encoding();
    }
    if(is_array($string) || $string instanceof Traversable) {
        $result = array();
        foreach($string as $key => $val) {
            $result[$key] = mb_explode($delimiter, $val, $limit, $encoding);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    $result = array();
    $currentpos = 0;
    $string_length = mb_strlen($string, $encoding);
    while($limit < 0 || count($result) < $limit) {
        $minpos = $string_length;
        $delim_index = null;
        foreach($delimiter as $index => $delim) {
            if(($findpos = mb_strpos($string, $delim, $currentpos, $encoding)) !== false) {
                if($findpos < $minpos) {
                    $minpos = $findpos;
                    $delim_index = $index;
                }
            }
        }
        $result[] = mb_substr($string, $currentpos, $minpos - $currentpos, $encoding);
        if($delim_index === null) {
            break;
        }
        $currentpos = $minpos + mb_strlen($delimiter[$delim_index], $encoding);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Then just use it the same way you use explode:

```
$content = mb_explode(' ', $output, $limit);
```

And for `implode`, [you shouldn't have any issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8564994/3305116).

Comment: how can i call it. it means by using $content = mb_explode('', $output, $limit);

Comment: It works just the same as `explode`. Just add the function code in your _functions.php_ file then replace `explode` by `mb_explode`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
    function custom_short_excerpt($excerpt){
    $limit = 200;

    if (strlen($excerpt) > $limit) {
        return substr($excerpt, 0, strpos($excerpt, ' ', $limit));
    }

    return $excerpt;
}

add_filter('the_excerpt', 'custom_short_excerpt');
```